# Should I use one form or Two?

Tags: forms, html

I have two forms (below) one is a trip calculator and one a spending money calculator which are very overwhelming due to the amount of events users can calculate.

There is a spending money radio on the trip calculator(if clicked "yes", will open the spending money calculator in new tab, functionality not added yet)

From a usability perspective should I:

Leave the two calculators separate as they are large enough visually already OR Add a conditional section to the main calculator where if clicked yes, the spending money calculator will open in the same page as the main calculator making the whole calculator longer if opened?

http://tripcalculator.travel2mania.com/WrestleMania.php

http://spendingcalculator.travel2mania.com/WrestleManiaspending.php

The calculators are built using a form builder, and there are 8 different files which make up the total code base, so its too large to attach here.

Comment: Could you please add screenshots to the post? The URLs are already deleted and the question can become irrelevant without your examples.

Comment: I decided to use one form as it was less messy See new firm below http://tripcalculator.travel2mania.com/WrestleManiaTravelCalculator.php

Answer (score 1):

In this design you have many places for improvment. I will list some of them;

- Layout is not good. You should provide stepper and separate sections in steps, providing option to navigate between steps. Ecommerce checkout design patterns can be easily applied
- Visual hierarchy is not clear - you should place better spacings, font sizes for headings, and distinguish in general sections
- For events field, where you dont know how much rows is needed you could provide "add new row" option for user. Also at the end of the row you can place "delete row" option.
- Overall cost on bottom could be sticky and designed differently, so that is always visible to the user.
- Users should not be able to scroll down after the content is finished. Lot of empty space

IMO, these are some the things that can be better.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I would say that if the tasks themselves are related but independent, you might prefer using one form, so that the user can chunk the workload effectively. Extending the form might make the task appear more complicated than it actually is.